# How to put file save location into a variable in VB with richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, savefiledialog

I am new to Visual Basic, so sorry if I this doesn't make amazing sense, but if you ask questions I should be able to clarify what I mean.

I am saving a file from a richtextbox using this code:

```
    Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFile.DefaultExt = "*.rtf"
    saveFile.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf"

    If (saveFile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) And (saveFile.FileName.Length) > 0 Then
        rtb_Output.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName, _
        RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

    End If
```

I have to have the user put in the file path and name, hence the Save Dialog box. 
I was wondering if there is any way for me to store the file path informatin in a variable to be used later?

Comment: Do you mean Dim path As String = saveFile.FileName ?

Comment: yarp, that's exactly what I meant! Thanks @varocarbas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *later* means in other parts of your code outside this method, then you have to declare a global variable at the class level and assign it to the value of FileName

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim savedFile As String


    Public Sub Form_Load(.....)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ButtonUploadFile_Click(....)

        if savedFile.Length > 0 Then
            .....
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub ButtonSave_Click(......)

         Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog()

         saveFile.DefaultExt = "*.rtf"
         saveFile.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf"

         If (saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) AndAlso _
            (saveFile.FileName.Length) > 0 Then
             savedFile = saveFile.FileName
             rtb_Output.SaveFile(savedFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
         End If
    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Thanks for the advice! the saveFile.FileName bit was the bit I was looking for, but thanks for the global variable advice... I haven't yet worked out whether it will be within the same function that I need that info or not.. I was still at the point where I was trying to work out if that was info I could get. Cheers

Comment: Of course, if you don't need that info outside the method, do not use a global variable. It is always a best practice to avoid them when possible.